# Django both installed via python3 and one via apt-get. Can I uninstall apt-get?

Tags: python3, pycharm

After spending a while to solve the `PyCharm` `ImportError`
It's the `"Couldn't import Django.` 
It's caused by me both installing `django` and `python with apt-get` and `python3`

```
Terminal
django-admin --version 
1.11.20

PyCharm IDE
 django-admin --version
2.2.4
```

I'm aware the

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/django/parent/dir python
>>> import django
```

solves the `importerror`

Do I need to an installation from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any package installed with `apt-get install` can be removed with `apt-get remove`.

Add `--simulate` to check first what will happen before removing the package, try this first:

```
sudo apt-get --simulate remove python-django
```

If you are happy with the output, remove those packages with:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-django
```

That will leave you only with the pip version, that normally is more recent than the apt-get one, if something gets wrong, reinstall that version:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall django
```

Hope it helps.